# How aggressive is the caching used?

Tags: discussion, caching

I refresh the 'Newest' tab of a particular tag every so often throughout the day to keep on top of new questions asked. However the caching used on Stack Overflow and presumably the other sites seems quite aggressive. I'll refresh and find a question asked 30-45 minutes ago that wasn't showing up when I last checked about 10 minutes ago (note: accurate testing not performed!).

What determines expiry of the cache and what is a good refresh interval to use?

Comment: Would it be possible for my keyboard to give me a mild electric shock if I hit F5 on SO more than once every 10 seconds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just checked:

- The list of question IDs returned from lists, views, and searches are cached for 2 minutes (120 seconds).
- The home page is cached at 60 seconds per tab.
- Related tag counts are cached for 10 minutes (600 seconds).