# There is a time delay on number of answers

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, caching

I answered a question that showed up on the main screen.  I went back to the main screen.  It said "0 Answers".  I refreshed.  It said "0 Answers".  I clicked the question again, refreshed, went back to the main screen again, refreshed, and it said "0 answers".  I waited 20 seconds, refreshed, and it said "1 answer".

I've never noticed this behavior before, and since I know some changes were made recently, I wanted to note it in case it's helpful to anyone on the SO team.

Comment: Note: I also noticed this question took about 30 seconds to show up on the feed of the main `meta.stackoverflow.com` screen.  It seems entirely plausible that the delay is intentionally there to manage the volume of HTTP requests by refreshing UI content globally in intervals.

Comment: [Caching](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/853/how-aggressive-is-the-caching-used). The answer is always [caching](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69164/does-stack-overflow-use-caching-and-if-so-how).

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta, That's what I figured.  The delay just seems more obvious than usual so I wanted to bring it to attention.

Comment: If you're talking about answer counts shown on the home page, we cache that list for 5 minutes, so all questions and their counts are static for the cache duration.