# Learn tag shows "zero questions tagged"

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, tags, caching

Today I searched [learn](/questions/tagged/learn) tag from the tag option in SO. I got this result:

[image]

It shows [learn](/questions/tagged/learn)**X 10** and "8 asked this month, 8 asked this year." When I click on the tag, or on the hyperlink "8 asked this month," I get this page:

[image: screenshot]

Here it shows "0 questions tagged."

Why does this happen? Is it a bug, or a known behavior?

How can I see the questions tagged [learn](/questions/tagged/learn)?

Comment: Caching. When in doubt, the answer is always caching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious reason here is most likely SO's very aggressive caching algorithms<sup>[[1]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/853/how-aggressive-is-the-caching-used)</sup>.

I think that the [learn](/questions/tagged/learn) got BURNiNATED in the past 10 minutes, and now your tag counts are all whacked up. Give it 5 or so minutes and it should sort itself out.

Answer (score 0):

What's happened is that there are no questions with the [learn](/questions/tagged/learn) tag, but there were some in the very recent past.

Give it 24 hours and the tag will be removed from the system so the info page (including wiki) will disappear.