# Browser caching has become a bit too aggressive

Tags: bug, status-completed, caching, browser-cache

Until a couple of hours ago, my usual experience on SE sites has been that the homepage, individual question pages, etc., would be revalidated and reloaded whenever I navigated around with Back and Forward buttons. As I understand it, this was accomplished with `maxage=0` or something very similar, and ensured that I would see the freshest content (subject to [server-side caching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/853/189912), of course).

This all changed while I was out to dinner, and now there is no `maxage=0` and the browser is caching pages *indefinitely*.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Load the front page of Server Fault, Mathematics, Programmers, Super User, or any site but Stack Overflow (where I haven't yet tested).
2. Click on a question.
3. Wait a few minutes or even hours, so that the front page should have received new content.
4. Click Back.

Expected results:

- The front page reloads, showing all new questions posted since I originally clicked the question in Step 2. This is what was occurring until this evening.

Actual results:

- The *cached* front page loads, showing only the questions present when I originally clicked the question in Step 2. No questions posted since that time appear. The timestamps show the wrong number of "minutes ago". On watching the Network tab, I see the browser does not attempt to revalidate the page.

More steps:

5. Click Forward to return to the question from Step 2 above.

Expected results:

- The question page is reloaded and any new votes, comments and answers appear.

Actual results:

- The *cached* question page is loaded, and appears as it did when originally accessed. No new votes, comments or answers are visible.

This is getting to be a real pain, as it means I'm almost constantly having to hit F5 as I navigate around the site, to be sure that I'm seeing something current.

Comment: As long as I've been paying attention (over a year?), if you use the back button it's from the browser cache. Not denying the devs have changed something, but are you sure a browser setting didn't change? My work around is to get in the habit of clicking the header logo if you want refreshed results. Use the back button if you wanted the exact same cached listing again.

Comment: Only if it was the NSA, because my house was empty at the time....It's certainly possible something changed on my end, but it doesn't seem very likely.

Comment: Marc Gravell [tuned caching parameters yesterday](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267816). Presumably that affected more pages than intended.

Comment: @MartijnPieters nah, same pages; just needed a minor tweak

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We made a [slight tweak to the `Cache-Control` header for logged in users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237626/23354); it looks like we didn't include the `max-age` in this (although to be honest, what you describe is pretty much what I would expect most browser behaviour to be *anyway*). I will be deploying a new build including the `max-age` shortly.

Comment: I liked it better when `max-age` was 0, but I guess 60 is better than nothing.

Comment: Chrome is behaving differently now that you altered the Cache-Control, which makes no sense. I *know* `max-age` didn't change, for example; it was 60 before, it is still 60 now. I have this idea that the `Vary` header was set to `*` before, now it is `Accept-Encoding`, and the `Expires` header is gone too. If Vary *was* set to `*` then that explains why Chrome didn't cache pages before. Did you change headers other than Cache-Control?

Comment: Right. I had thought this was fixed, but Firefox is still not revalidating after 60 seconds.

Comment: The *correct* way to handle this is for Stack Exchange to produce ETags for pages, and set `Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate`. The If-Modified-Since header on the request then lets you *very quickly* determine if a page is still fresh (e.g. the local Redis-cached ETag matches or it doesn't based on the last time the page was changed).

Comment: @Martijn we really really don't need an etag to know whether the stackoverflow homepage has changed in a minute :) and since we display relative times, the same is true elsewhere

Comment: Right, and since I never paid attention to wether clicking on the title gave a cached copy or fresh (I always just used reload), I'll step back from the whole 'Vary' issue too. There is a simple work-around, just use reload, done.

Comment: Can the caching be completely disabled some places such as the reputation and responses tab? They keep highlighting the same updates over and over again.

Comment: It's really annoying for `max-age` to be 60... Chrome cached it *too* much, I had to do a hard refresh to get fresh content. Also see http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2285529#2285529.

Comment: @hichris will probably change that today

Comment: I'm pretty unhappy with the change, whatever it is.  I don't like leaving a comment or voting, clicking a link, then clicking back and seeing my comment or vote has disappeared.  This didn't happen before.

Comment: Not sure what you guys did, or exactly when, but it appears to be fixed _now_.

Answer (score 1):

I am having this problem as well, here is my experience

When I go to my user page, I will have a blue number on `reputation` tab.
Before, I would click it, then if I clicked back to `summary` tab blue number is
gone. Now blue number persists until I press <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Before when I would ask a question, if a new answer was given I could click the
question title to refresh and see the new answer. Now I can only see the new
answer if I hit <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Comment: I will investigate

Comment: Oh, just for those who didn't know... Pressing 'Ctrl+F5' will do a full cache clearing whilst refreshing the page... very handy to know instead of going through the browsers settings or having to install a third-party cache clearing addon/plugin.