# Comment text cut off on the mobile site

Tags: bug, comments, mobile-web, mobile-safari

This is the first time I have connected to the mobile site in quite a while. While using safari on a iPhone 4 I have noticed that the comments on a lot of posts are not wrapping correctly in portrate mode.

[Here is a example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237600/browser-caching-has-become-a-bit-too-aggressive#comment779032_237624)

Portrate:

> [image]

Landscape:

> [image]

Comment: Sorry, forgot to search before posting.