# Please fix my back button

Tags: bug, status-completed, caching, back-button

Here's a recipe for confusion:

1. Load a page on Stack Exchange.
2. Do anything that updates the page via JS―leave a comment, vote, etc.
3. Leave the page by following a link.
4. Use the browser's back button to return to the original page.

You'll be unpleasantly surprised to find that all the updates from step 2 are gone. This is really confusing, and it wasn't true two weeks ago.  It's a major usability problem.  I assume it's due to [the `Cache-Control` header changes,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237624/215040) since I first noticed the problem on either August 5 or 6.

#### Leave a comment, click a link, go back, and the comment is gone.

Stack Exchange used to provide users with updated pages without making them hit the reload button all the time.  Now several times each day I have to figure out the page is out of date on my own and hit reload.  It's confusing every single time.

#### Please fix my back button!

Comment: I've been noticing this over the last couple of days too. Using Firefox 31.0.

Comment: This has been the case for eons, certainly in Chrome. The cache headers have been changed to prevent public caches (proxy servers) from caching the response, and the browser has been instructed *not* to cache the page at all now.

Comment: See [Ajax, back button and DOM updates](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1195440) for example, from 2009. The behaviour you claim changed only recently, has been the status quo for years now, because Stack Overflow pages use a beforeunload event handler.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh, it's too bad it was always broken in Chrome.  That must be irritating for Chrome users.

Comment: The back button has been broken in so many web applications for so long that I seldom use it anymore.  I just assume that it won't work.

Comment: Just checking what happens to this.  Can't repro using Firefox.  BTW, what's Chrome?

Comment: @0xdeadbeef http://www.lenntech.com/periodic/elements/cr.htm

Comment: Even though this was never fixed, I've gotten used to it, so it doesn't seem like a big deal anymore.  I just give SE lots of extra reloads these days.

Answer (score 2):

OK; I'm trying a slightly different configuration - that `no-cache` was perhaps too aggressive. This should be here on meta in about 10 minutes.